# Edición de archivos .docx con XML en C# Error al mostrar imagen insertada

Tags: c#, xml, imagen, docx, openxml

**Issue:**
Se necesita agregar una imagen a un archivo de extensión .docx por medio de la libreria OpenXML.

**Resources:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-a-word-processing-document

**Respuestas:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384826/creating-an-imagepart-isnt-saving-the-relationship-in-openxml/19435044#19435044  - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568401/c-sharp-wordprocessingdocument-insert-an-image-in-a-cell-image-cannot-be-dis

**Código:**

```
var path = "pathToFile";
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
   //Creates a in memory for the file
   stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   using (WordprocessingDocument doc =  WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
   {
      //Gets the MainPart from the file .docx
      MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
      //Sets ImagePart and add itto MainPart
      ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);

      //Gets file from path
      //Imagen format: .png
      using (FileStream imgStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, 
      FileAccess.ReadWrite))
      {
          image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgStream);
          imagePart.FeedData(imgStream);
      }
      Drawing imageElement = GetImageElement(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart),"logoImage","image",image.Height,image.Width);
      //Adds imageElement to the body
      body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(imageElement)));
      doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
   }
}
//Codigo para devolver imagen a un ImageElement
private static Drawing GetImageElement(string imagePartId,string fileName,string pictureName,double width,double height)
    {
        double englishMetricUnitsPerInch = 914400;
        double pixelsPerInch = 96;

        //calculate size in emu
        double emuWidth = width * englishMetricUnitsPerInch / pixelsPerInch;
        double emuHeight = height * englishMetricUnitsPerInch / pixelsPerInch;

        var element = new Drawing(
            new XmlDrawing.Wordprocessing.Inline(
                new XmlDrawing.Wordprocessing.Extent { Cx = 990000L/*(Int64Value)emuWidth*/, Cy = 792000L/*(Int64Value)emuHeight*/ },
                new XmlDrawing.Wordprocessing.EffectExtent { LeftEdge = 0L, TopEdge = 0L, RightEdge = 0L, BottomEdge = 0L },
                new XmlDrawing.Wordprocessing.DocProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = pictureName },
                new XmlDrawing.Wordprocessing.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                new XmlDrawing.GraphicFrameLocks { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                new XmlDrawing.Graphic(
                    new XmlDrawing.GraphicData(
                        new XmlDrawing.Pictures.Picture(
                            new XmlDrawing.Pictures.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                new XmlDrawing.Pictures.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)0U, Name = fileName },
                                new XmlDrawing.Pictures.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                            new XmlDrawing.Pictures.BlipFill(
                                new XmlDrawing.Blip(
                                    new XmlDrawing.BlipExtensionList(
                                        new XmlDrawing.BlipExtension { Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}" }))
                                {
                                    Embed = imagePartId,
                                    CompressionState = XmlDrawing.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                },
                                        new XmlDrawing.Stretch(new XmlDrawing.FillRectangle())),
                            new XmlDrawing.Pictures.ShapeProperties(
                                new XmlDrawing.Transform2D(
                                    new XmlDrawing.Offset { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                    new XmlDrawing.Extents { Cx = 990000L/*(Int64Value)emuWidth*/, Cy = 792000L/*(Int64Value)emuHeight*/ }),
                                new XmlDrawing.PresetGeometry(
                                    new XmlDrawing.AdjustValueList())
                                { Preset = XmlDrawing.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle })))
                    {
                        Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
                    }))
            {
                DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                EditId = "50D07946"
            });
        return element;
    }
```

**Excepted:**
Se espera que después del proceso, en la parte donde se haga el append del *ImageElement* se pueda ver la imagen en dónde se asigne.

**Result: **
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te invito a que des un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas como preguntar, no te toma mas de un minuto.

Answer (score 0):

La clase FileStream solo permite 1 sola lectura, la cual estás usando para obtener información de la imagen: altura y longitud. Por eso debes volver a usar otro stream reader o copiar el arreglo de bytes para los dos objetos que quieres utilizar, abajo un ejemplo funcional:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
   //Creates a in memory for the file
   stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   using (WordprocessingDocument doc =  WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
   {
      //Gets the MainPart from the file .docx
      MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
      //Sets ImagePart and add itto MainPart
      ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);

      //Gets file from path
      //Imagen format: .png
      using (FileStream imgStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, 
      FileAccess.ReadWrite))
      {
          //solo te permite usarlo 1 sola vez
          image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgStream);
      }

      using (FileStream imgStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, 
      FileAccess.ReadWrite))
      {
          //solo te permite usarlo 1 sola vez
          imagePart.FeedData(imgStream);
      }

      Drawing imageElement = GetImageElement(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart),"logoImage","image",image.Height,image.Width);
      //Adds imageElement to the body
      body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(imageElement)));
      doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
   }
}
```